# Network state error navigator.connection.type return 0 always with phone gap 2.8.1

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am using navigator.connection.type for the phonegap version 2.8.1 with sencha touch build 
Am getting 0 always for even network is or off in device

can any one help me out whats the issue is

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/index.html

I have below permissions for manifest file too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add

NETWORK_STATE_PERMISSION
and maybe
INTERNET

permissions to Android manifest ?

Comment: Yes i have permissions as well